# How do I pass a buffer as a piped input to a node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I want to send a buffer as a piped input to a node script on the terminal. Thus I created a script ping.js with the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

function bufferDemo() {
  var objBuffer = new Buffer(29);
  objBuffer.writeUInt32LE(29,0);
  objBuffer.write('{message:"pingfrompingjs"}',4);

  return objBuffer;
}

bufferDemo();
```

Then I ran the following command on the command line:

```
 ./ping.js | ./index.js
```

I also tried:

```
 ./ping.js > out.json
```

out.json is empty so obviously the ping.js is not passing the buffer. How do I achieve this? I am relatively new to node.

Comment: so as colleagues suggested use something like `console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));` because `|` works with unix based `stdin` and `stdout`. so you want to pass data via that channel first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually outputting anything by returning the value in your function. You should be writing to [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout):

```
process.stdout.write(objBuffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

`return`ing from the function is no effect whatsoever. If you want your command to output something, you have to write to [`stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) (or `stderr`):

```
process.stdout.write(objBuffer);
```